# Converting string to int changes the value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, integer

I'm trying to convert a string value I retrieved from an XML parser into an integer. Unfortunately, I'm finding that the integer value is not reflecting the number in the string, and I can't figure out why. Here is my code:

```
int maxTweetID = [[[_dataArray lastObject]tweetID]intValue];

NSLog(@"String Value of tweet ID: %@",[[_dataArray lastObject]tweetID]);
NSLog(@"Int Value of tweet ID: %i",[[[_dataArray lastObject]tweetID]intValue]);
```

and here is what I'm getting from the debugger:

```
2012-05-15 10:58:44.395 nearYou[2460:707] String Value of tweet ID: 202425636143370242
2012-05-15 10:58:44.396 nearYou[2460:707] Int Value of tweet ID: 2147483647
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is much too large to fit in a 32 bit `int`. What you want to do is use a `long` instead:

```
long maxTweetID = [[[_dataArray lastObject]tweetID]longValue];
```

**EDIT:**

You actually need to use `long long` in Objective-C:

```
long long maxTweetID = [[[_dataArray lastObject]tweetID]longLongValue];
```

Comment: There's no method `longValue` on `NSString`. There's `integerValue`, which will be 64 bits on the desktop, and there's `longLongValue`.

Comment: yup this works too. I'm having trouble changing the value with this code: double newestID = (maxID - 1.0); any idea why? maxID is a double as well

Answer (score 1):

The number in the string is too large to be stored as an integer. The highest integer possible with 32 bits is 2.147.483.647. Try using a long.

Comment: awesome this works. follow up question: can't I subtract 1 from that value?  double newestID = (maxID - 1.0);
    NSLog(@"newest ID is %f and maxID is %f",newestID,maxID); Any ideas?