# NSString intValue deforming actual number

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, integer

I was making a basic method that takes a Flickr image URL and returns the image's ID.
I'm passing the method the `NSString` `@"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5183/5629026092_c6762a118f"`.

The goal is to return the int: `5629026092`, which is in the image's URL and is the image's ID.

Here is my method:

```
-(int)getImageIDFromFlickrURL:(NSString *)imageURL{
    NSArray *objectsInURLArray = [imageURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *lastObjectInFlickrArray = [objectsInURLArray lastObject];
    NSArray *dirtyFlickrIdArray = [lastObjectInFlickrArray componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
    NSString *flickIDString = [dirtyFlickrIdArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"flickr id string: %@",flickIDString);
    int flickrID = [flickIDString intValue];
    NSLog(@"id: %i",flickrID);
    return flickrID;
}
```

The output in the console is:

```
2012-05-26 13:30:25.771 TestApp[1744:f803] flickr id string: 5629026092
2012-05-26 13:30:25.773 TestApp[1744:f803] id: 2147483647
```

Why is calling `intValue` deforming the actual number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string to int in Objective C changing the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606281/converting-string-to-int-in-objective-c-changing-the-value)

Comment: You can use NSInteger instead of int to store the larger number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `long long` instead, your number is greater than `int` can handle (max being `2147483647` as you can see in your second log)

Answer (score 1):

Your value is too big to represent in 32 bits. The biggest value you can store in a signed 32 bit integer (int) is 2147483647. For unsigned ints, it's 4294967295. You need to convert to a long long integer to represent a number as big as 5629026092.

You'll probably need to create a number formatter for that. I'm no expert on number formatters, and always have to dig out the documentation to figure out how to use them.

I just tried it, and this code works:

```
  NSString *numberString = @"5629026092";

  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

  NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString: numberString];
  long long value = [number longLongValue];
  NSLog(@"%@ = %qi", numberString, value);
  [formatter release];
```

You could also convert the string to a C string and use scanf, come to think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy ^^: INT_MAX  Maximum value for a variable of type int. 2147483647

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a convenient way to do it:

```
NSString *flickIDString = [dirtyFlickrIdArray objectAtIndex:0]; // read some huge number into a string

// read into a NSNumber object or a long long variable. you choose
NSNumber *flickIDNumber = flickIDString.longLongValue;
long long flickIDLong = flickIDString.longLongValue;
```